# Как проигрывать видео в videoview в яндекс или гугл диске?

Tags: java, android, видео, videoview

Хочу проигрывать видео с интернета, лежащее на яндекс или гугл диске.
Просто передать ссылку  в ресурс видео не получается.
Снизу пример кода, как я пытался это сделать с гугл диска, но таким образом видео не воспроизводиться:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // установите свой путь к файлу на SD-карточке

    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vview);

    String videoSource ="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ql63EqziGH8480Fl7JhLnd1LfPWHe7vd/view?usp=sharing";
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoSource));

    videoView.setVideoPath(videoSource);


    videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    videoView.requestFocus(0);
    videoView.start(); // начинаем воспроизведение автоматически


}
```

Comment: нужно использовать ссылку для скачивания, а не для sharing

Comment: Спасибо, сработало!